# Target specific class + numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I'm trying to get images of different sizes to appear randomly one by one around the center of the page, for now I managed to have them randomly appear and to have them with different width and therefor height. However I am SURE I can target all of the classes instead of copying every single code with a different name? I remember once seeing a function that targeted a class and automatically the number that followed it, like .item +(and then the extension?)

Any tips regarding letting them appear around the center instead of spread across are welcome. I patched this together with a lot of different codes, so it's bit of a Frankenstein.

```
$(".grid-item").hide().each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(i*500).fadeIn(500);
});

var pane_width = $(".random-pane").width() - $(".grid-item").width();
var pane_height = $(".random-pane").height() - $(".grid-item").height();

$(".random-pane").children().each( function(){

  var x = Math.round(Math.random() * pane_width);
  var y =  Math.round(Math.random() * pane_height);

  $(this).css("top",y);
  $(this).css("left",x);

});

var rand=Math.floor(Math.random()*30)+10;
var width=Math.round(($(window).width()/100)*rand);
$('.item-1').width(width);

var rand=Math.floor(Math.random()*30)+10;
var width=Math.round(($(window).width()/100)*rand);
$('.item-2').width(width);

var rand=Math.floor(Math.random()*30)+10;
var width=Math.round(($(window).width()/100)*rand);
$('.item-3').width(width);

var rand=Math.floor(Math.random()*30)+10;
var width=Math.round(($(window).width()/100)*rand);
$('.item-4').width(width);

var rand=Math.floor(Math.random()*30)+10;
var width=Math.round(($(window).width()/100)*rand);
$('.item-5').width(width);
```

Comment: Regarding `Any tips regarding letting them appear around the center instead of spread across are welcome. I patched this together with a lot of different codes, so it's bit of a Frankenstein.` Your question should focus on a single problem. Separate solutions should have a separate question so they can be useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target all elements containing `item-` in their class, you can use

```
$('[class*="item-"]').each(function(){
    // Run code here for each match using `$(this)`
})
```

You cannot guarantee that it's going to be followed by a number. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Having said that, if you can modify the HTML, I would give them all the same class and just use `.item` to prevent false positives. For example, in cause you have another element with the class `special-item-highlight`

**Example:**

```js
$('[class*="item-"]').each(function() {
  $(this).width(Math.random() * 300)
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item-1">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<div class="item-2">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<div class="item-3">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wauw! That seriously helped. I have it like this now: $('[class*="item-"]').each(function() {
  $(this).width((Math.random() * 300) +100);
})